# Fourth Order PDE question. Help please

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was hoping someone could help me with the following question. I have separated the variables but seem to be a little stuck with the spatial component. Could someone provide some help please?

[image: Fourth Order PDE]

Here is my progress thus far:
[image: Left is the working for the Temporal and Right is the spatial component]

Comment: Please show your solution so we can see where you are stuck and why. Just saying you separated the variables doesn't help much. Unless you want someone to do the whole problem for you

Comment: Please see my working attached to the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial answer focusing the second item.

After the Laplace transform we have

$$
s^2 U(s,x)+U_{xxxx}(s,x) = s\sin x
$$

which solved with the boundary conditions

$$
U(s,0)=U(s,\pi)=U_{xx}(s,0)=U_{xx}(s,\pi) = 0
$$

gives

$$
U(s,x) = \frac{s\sin x}{s^2+1}
$$

and after inverting

$$
u(t,x) = \cos t\sin x
$$